# JavaScript function executing too soon

Tags: jquery, callback

In the example below, `myFonk` is called instantly; it doesn't wait for the click event. Why not?

```
    function myFonk(info) {
        $("#result").html(info);
    }

    function getText(text) {
        return function () {
            myFonk(text);
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#b1").click(getText("getText"));
        $("#b2").click(myFonk("myFonk"));
    });
```

Comment: A badly formatted piece of code with a question in the title? In general we prefer a bit more effort made with questions here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever we write the function name with () it calls that function instantly
hence 
`myFonk("myFonk")` is not correct way..

Write in following manner.

```
function myFonk(info) {
    $("#result").html(info);
}

function getText(text) {
    return function () {
        myFonk(text);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#b1").click(getText("getText"));
    $("#b2").click(function () {
        myFonk("myFonk")
    });
});
```

Comment: In short add a callback function and then write your code in it. 
Use function(){}; statement and write your code within this.

Comment: You're welcome.
Please mark as correct answer if you got the correct ouput

Comment: I'll not downvote, but code in answers generally should be well indented, as an example to readers of how code should be presented generally. @James has done this for you.

Comment: Thanks James, Thanks to you also halfer, I'll keep this in mind

Comment: This answer made me realize that i wrote my function with the parentheses in a watch statement which made it execute too soon... So if you have `myFonk("myFonk)` in your watch (at least in IE, didn't test in Chrome etc) it will execute too... Could smack myself in the head

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're not passing a reference to the functions.  You're calling the functions and using the results as the event handlers for `click`.

This will fix that for you...

```
function myFonk(info) {
    $("#result").html(info);
}

function getText(text){
    return function() {
        myFonk(text);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#b1").click(function() {
        getText("getText")
    });
    $("#b2").click(function() {
        myFonk("myFonk")
    });
});
```

Comment: That'll work, but it doesn't explain what's actually happening.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#b1").click(getText("getText"));
});
```

What you're doing here is calling the function `getText("getText")` and passing the result of that call to `$("#b1").click()`. You don't want to pass the *result* of the function. What you want to do is to pass the function itself. So rewrite as,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#b1").click(function() {
        return getText("getText");
    });
});
```

If the function you were interested in had no parameters (let's say, for example, that you wanted to call a function `hello()`, with no parameters, you could do it the same way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#b1").click(function() {
        return hello();
    });
});
```

... or you could simplify it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#b1").click(hello);
});
```

Note: you're passing `hello` (the function itself), not `hello()` (which would execute the function immediately and return the result to the `click()` function.