# jQuery .ajax calls success function before sending request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to make a **chatbox** for my website. Basically, the user types their chat into the textarea with id chat-input. When the user clicks on the Enter button, it calls the `sendChat()` function. This function sends the request to a php file on the server which adds the user's chat to the chatlog *(a text file on the server)*. On success, the javascript is supposed to call the update() function which performs a get request to the chatlog.txt file on the server and load it into the div with id prev-chats. The problem is that the javascript calls update() before the server responds, and so the prev-chats is not updated until the page is refreshed. I can tell this because
**a)** the chats are not updating until I refresh the page, and

**b)** In Google Chrome, after pressing F12, the network tab shows the GET request for chatLog.txt before the POST request for submitting the chat.

**Here is my HTML code**

```
            <div id="prev-chats" class="well"></div>
            <textarea id="chat-input"></textarea>
            <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="sendChat()">Enter</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="update()">Update</button>
            <script type="text/javascript">

                function sendChat(){
                    var message = $("#chat-input").val();
                    var datavar = {"message": message};
                    console.log("Sending message to server");
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        async: "false",
                        url: "chatResponse.php",
                        data: datavar,
                        success: update()
                    });
                    console.log("Message sent to server");
                };
                function update(){
                    $("#prev-chats").load("chatLog.txt");
                    console.log("chat updated");
                }

                update();
            </script>
```

And here is my PHP code

```
<?php
$chatLog = fopen("chatLog.txt","a+") or die("Eror loading chat... Please try again later");
$chat = htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);
fwrite($chatLog, $chat . "<br>");
fclose($chatLog); 
?>
```

Here is what appears in my console

```
(index):85 chat updated
(index):72 Sending message to server
(index):85 chat updated
(index):81 Message sent to server
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript function executing too soon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15002306/javascript-function-executing-too-soon).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using

```
success: update
```

instead of

```
success: update()
```

Comment: Is there any reason why that works? Is it because the function is automatically called with the data and status parameters?

Comment: @KenthMirta A little late, but yes, and this solution is more elegant than the accepted answer. You can imagine `success` as being a variable for a function, but `update()` is a *call* to the function `update`. `update` itself is the function you want to pass to that method.

Comment: @KenthMirta So the accepted answer passes an anonymous function to the `success` parameter, which then calls the `update` function, while this answer directly passes the update function. A function *call* like `update()` executes the function when you pass this line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Change your ajax like this

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    async: "false",
                    url: "chatResponse.php",
                    data: datavar,
                    success:function(){ update()}
                });
```